# How to evaulate salesmen objectively?

Tags: statistics

Each salesman will sell product to three kinds of person,each kind of customers has a different response rate,I will mark these customers level A,level B and level C.

According data here,how to evaluate if a saleman is better by their response rate.Any idea is highly appreciated.

```
+----------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| sales_no | levelA_customers | levelA_success | levelB_customers | levelB_success | levelC_customers | levelC_success |
+----------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| no1      |              158 |              5 |             1254 |             11 |             5423 |              8 |
| no2      |              300 |              6 |             2236 |             15 |             3687 |             11 |
| no3      |              198 |              4 |             1727 |             18 |             2567 |             14 |
| no4      |              234 |              7 |              987 |             23 |               99 |              0 |
| no5      |              388 |              2 |              876 |              4 |             1116 |             23 |
+----------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+
```

sales_no is id of saleman
levelA_customers is how many level A customers have been selled
levelA_success is how many level A customers have buy the product

Comment: Please don't use terms that are gender-exclusive, when there are perfectly good words ("salesperson") that are inclusive.

Comment: this term(Travelling salesman problem) is terminology in Operations Research and I don't think better words exists.